# Magento 2 VAT tax is visible for only specific country

Tags: magento, magento2, tax

**On the UK the VAT is calculated.**

[image]

**On the Ireland  the VAT is added on the total but not on the VAT column**

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Multi store environment.
One for UK and another for Ireland.

Now modify your checkout page as per your requirement.

By default Magento does not have a configuration feature that allow different checkout themes based on country.

Comment: i don't want a different theme here, i just want the VAT to be visible that's it

Comment: Is your product price defined via admin has tax inclusive or exclusive.With Tax inclusive there are known issue and not recommeded.